# Prevent Default Scene Creation

Tags: python, vpython

I have learned that vpython automatically creates a display called 'scene' when visual is imported. Is there anyway that I can prevent this from happening and then manually add my objects to a display of my liking. Here is the functionality I am looking for:

```
import vis

vis.scene.disable
my_scene = vis.display()
my_object = box()
my_scene.objects.append(my_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

`scene` is just the default display created. You can just create a new `display` object, and it becomes the new default one.

```
from visual import *

d = display()
obj = box()             # You could also specify display=d
print obj.display == d  # Prints True
```